# how to use assert_frame_equal in unittest

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, python-unittest

New to unittest package. 
I'm trying to verify the DataFrame returned by a function through the following code. Even though I hardcoded the inputs of `assert_frame_equal` to be equal (`pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0])`), the unittest still fails. Anyone would like to explain why it happens?

```
import unittest
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
class TestSplitWeight(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_allZero(self):
        #splitWeight(pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0]),10)
        self.assert_frame_equal(pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0]),pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0]))

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestSplitWeight)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

```
Error: AttributeError: 'TestSplitWeight' object has no attribute 'assert_frame_equal'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`assert_frame_equal()` comes from the `pandas.testing` package, not from the `unittest.TestCase` class. Replace:

```
self.assert_frame_equal(pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0]),pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0]))
```

with:

```
assert_frame_equal(pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0]), pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0]))
```

---

When you had `self.assert_frame_equal`, it tried to find `assert_frame_equal` attribute on the `unittest.TestCase` instance, and, since there is not `assert_frame_equal` attribute or method exposed on an `unittest.TestCase` class, it raised an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 25):

alecxe answer is incomplete, you can indeed use pandas' `assert_frame_equal()` with `unittest.TestCase`, using [`unittest.TestCase.addTypeEqualityFunc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addTypeEqualityFunc)

```py
import unittest
import pandas as pd
import pandas.testing as pd_testing

class TestSplitWeight(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertDataframeEqual(self, a, b, msg):
        try:
            pd_testing.assert_frame_equal(a, b)
        except AssertionError as e:
            raise self.failureException(msg) from e

    def setUp(self):
        self.addTypeEqualityFunc(pd.DataFrame, self.assertDataframeEqual)

    def test_allZero(self):
        self.assertEqual(pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0]), pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0]))
```

Comment: I have duplicate your code and I got the following error: `TypeError: addTypeEqualityFunc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'function'`. Do you know why?

Comment: What is the purpose of msg here? Can the message of assert_frame_equal be somehow passed to assertEqual?

Comment: @fato39 the msg parameter allows to pass-on an additional message, additionaly the raise...from construct used there wraps the original pandas exception into a unittest-compatible failureException.

Answer (score -1):

If you import this, the problem is gone.

```
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal  # <-- for testing dataframes
```